# Flask app runs fine locally, but error accessing db on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I have a small Flask app (code below) that's basically just using peewee to access a Postgres database. It works fine when I run it locally, but I get a generic 500 Internal Server Error when I try to run it on Heroku.

Here's the code

```
from flask import Flask
from peewee import *
import logging
import os
import urlparse

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')

urlparse.uses_netloc.append('postgres')
url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
DATABASE = {
    'name': url.path[1:],
    'user': url.username,
    'password': url.password,
    'host': url.hostname,
    'port': url.port,
}

db = PostgresqlDatabase(DATABASE['name'], host=DATABASE['host'], user=DATABASE['user'], port=DATABASE['port'], password=DATABASE['password'])

class Team(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
        db_table = 'd_team'

    team_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    team_name = CharField()

@app.route('/')
def home():
    teams = [t.team_name for t in Team.select()]
    return str(teams)
```

And here's what I see when I run `heroku logs` (nothing useful...not sure why).

```
2014-06-29T19:52:20.242902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-06-29T19:52:23.081153+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn main:app`
2014-06-29T19:52:26.240427+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-ocean-5904.herokuapp.com request_id=c1c365ba-94a6-4405-9812-23e18fe853c4 fwd="208.72.142.70" dyno=web.1 connect=70ms service=309ms status=500 bytes=244
2014-06-29T19:52:25.067383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-06-29T19:52:22.220811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

I'm able to get simple "Hello World" messages to display fine, so the problem seems to be the database call. So I've tried accessing the production database when running the app locally, and that works fine locally as well. I've also checked that the `DATABASE_URL` variable is correctly set in production, and it is.

Any ideas what's wrong? Is there a way of getting a more useful trace?

Comment: Have you tried turning on [debugging](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/)?

Comment: @dirn Yeah, I tried setting `app.config['DEBUG'] = True`, but it doesn't seem to change anything -- I still don't see anything useful in the logs.